# How to submit form after validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to submit a form after the validation succeeds, so I've run the below code, and both operations perform at same time. I also tried to submit handler method, but it only gets errors. My code looks like this:

```
$("#request_form").validate({
    debug: false,
    onfocusout: function(element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    errorClass : 'has-error',
    rules: {
        Subject : "required",
        Screen: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        Subject : "Subject cannot be empty",
        Screen: "Screen  cannot be empty"
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});



$("#request_form").on('submit',
              (function(e) 
               {
               $("#request_form").validate(); 
               $("#request_form").valid()
               {
                   alert("test");
                   var action = "Provide_Feedback";
                   var form = $('form')[0]; 
                   var formData = new FormData(form);

                   formData.append('action','Provide_Feedback');
                   e.preventDefault();

                   $.ajax({
                   url: "support_update.php", 
                   type: "POST",             
                   data: formData, 
                   contentType: false,      
                   cache: false,            
                   processData:false,        
                   success: function(data)   
                   {            
                       if (data == "200") {
                       alert("Your Request Sent.");
                       window.location = 'provide_feedback.php';
                       }
                       else {   
                       alert("There was an error occurred!");
                       }                 

                   }
                   });

               }
               }));
```

Comment: This call getting recursive, b'coz you are calling validate function inside the submit function & calling submit function inside validate.

Comment: no error, both operation perform simultaneously. validate error and form submit alert display at same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `submitHandler` of plugin only fires when form is valid. You really don't need your own handler as well.

Put your ajax inside `submitHandler` and remove `form.submit()`.

`form.submit()` is telling browser to send the form through default process, which is clearly not what you want if you are wanting to submit it with ajax.

Considering that you are doing a redirect with javascript in ajax success, it's unclear why you really want to use ajax in the first place however

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I just remove form.submit() and put my ajax code, form validate correctly but now work ajax operation.

Answer (score 0):

Inside submit handler remove `form.submit();` & return a numaral value like `return 1;` ie

`submitHandler: function(form) {
        return 1;
    }`

And inside `$("#request_form").on('submit',(function(e)` call validate function & check if the return value is equal to 1 & proceed further like:

```
 $("#request_form").on('submit',(function(e) 
{
  if($("#request_form").validate()!=1)
  {
     return false;
  }
//Continue your code here
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi , by using above code changes form  submission and ajax call not working.

Comment: why not just use the submitHandler option properly as it is documented?